# How to recover Perforce history on a moved directory

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have a branch on Perforce, where I changes the directory structure of the project using Rename/Move command.

During merging back to the mainstream, Something went wrong that caused Perforce to think of the new structure as a whole-new directories.

Subsequently, the history of the files in the new directory structure is totally unrelated to the history of the same files before changing the structure.

Is there anyway to recover this situation ? Or ask Perforce to append the old history with the new history ?

Answer (score 2):

> Something went wrong that caused Perforce to think of the new structure as a whole-new directories.

Usually if this happens it means someone didn't use the "rename/move" command and used some other method to rename instead (i.e. they did something that adds the new directory as a new set of files independent of the originals rather than an atomic rename of an existing set of files).  It's impossible for me to say how to "recover" without seeing what the history of the files looks like now so I can reverse-engineer what the "something went wrong" was.

I'd recommend either posting on the Perforce forums or contacting Perforce technical support so that somebody with expertise can wheedle the necessary data out of you (I can intuit that this will require an amount of back and forth that stackoverflow frowns on -- "what were the branches you were merging from and to", "okay, now run THIS command to see the history of that branch and send me the output," "okay, which of these five merge operations I can see in the history is the one you're talking about,") and propose a solution.

From another answer:

> So, for a file a/b/c, you can look at the by using the -i option where appropriate. For example, p4 filelog -li a/b/c.

This is not necessary if files are renamed via the "move/rename" command, so if you need to use "filelog -i" to see file history, the files were definitely renamed by some other method.  (The "p4 move" command was added in 2009 so long-time Perforce users will sometimes use other workflows.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the "move/rename" integration history details. I've been using Perforce since 2000, and still do `p4 integrate` followed by `p4 delete`.

Comment: Caught out!  :D  Yeah, the new "move" command has a bunch of special semantics designed to prevent a lot of the historic problems with Perforce "losing" history of renamed files.  Check out the "remapping renamed files" section of this white paper, which talks about how "moved" files implicitly modify branch mappings to make sure changes merge correctly: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/sam_stafford/doc/Base%20Picking.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will read it in detail later but a quick scan reminded me of some old interactions with Perforce support, and a look through my email history found an interaction with you on this subject from 2005!

Comment: If you talked to Perforce support about branching/merging at any point between 2000 and 2010 you probably talked to me.  ;)